# Unable to access method of thread class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm unable to call any functions of R1 from my main class? (seton(), setoff(), etc.)

```
public class Threads implements Runnable {
  public String threadName;
  private volatile boolean running = true;

  public Threads( String name) {
    threadName = name;
  }

  public void setoff() {
    running = false; //this.running = false;
  }

  public void seton() {
    running = true; //this.running = true;
  }

  public void run() {
    while(this.running) {
      System.out.println("running");
    }
    if(this.running ==false) {
      System.out.println("stopped");
    }
    System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
  }
}
```

--end class

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {  
  Thread R1 = null;

  public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();
  }

  private void jbtnstartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    R1 = new Thread(new Threads("Thread 1"));
    R1.start();
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call any methods of your `Threads` class, because you don't have a reference to the object of that type.

Change your code to:

```
Threads R1 = new Threads("Thread 1");
Thread thread = new Thread(R1);
thread.start();

Thread.sleep(1000);
R1.setoff();
```

---

Also, `if(this.running ==false)` should be written `if (! this.running)`.

Or better yet, that line should be removed. The *only* way for that line to be executed, is for the preceding `while` loop to exit, which only happens when `this.running` is false, so the test in the `if` statement is redundant.

Comment: Thanks, just got it working. The not running part was just a test without doing proper debugging, will be removing that in the end.

Comment: The variable name `R1` does not conform to the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it working after;

```
Threads mythread = new Threads("222");
Thread R1 = new Thread(mythread);
mythread.seton();
R1.start();
```